# Prevent additional line break when pressing return inside parenthesis

Tags: pycharm

When pressing the return key with the caret placed inside of parenthesis (e.g. from a function call) PyCharm automatically inserts another line break after the caret so that the caret is on a blank line:

```
print(‸)
```

Pressing return at the location denoted by `‸` results in this state:

```
print(
    ‸
)
```

This is all well and helpful *if* I'd want to have that closing parenthesis on a line by its own. But I don't. :) I like to format complex function calls like this (maybe LISP had an excessive influence on me):

```
'...'.format(
    eggs = get_eggs(...),
    spam = get_spam(
        'spam',
        'spam',
        'more spam'),
    bacon = get_bacon(...))
```

Is there a way to disable the automatic behavior of PyCharm to insert that second newline?

Comment: Check Code Style settings for Python code: `Settings/Preferences | Editor | Code Style` -- there should be a setting that would be called something like "function call parenthesis" or similar -- options would be like "placing closing parenthesis at new line" or ".. end of the line" -- this sort of things (P.S. I'm not using PyCharm myself  -- only suggesting what I see fro JS/PHP)

Comment: @LazyOne PyCharm seems to have that option only for the `}` of dictionary literals. :/